# How to communicate spring app to mysql in docker compose?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker-compose

Although I've rudimentary managed Spring boot docker service to initiate after mysql docker service, there is still a communications link failure from the app.
I don't know what else to do, I've tried too many things now.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: hernidb
    image: mysql
    volumes:
     - "./waitForMySQL.sh:/usr/local/bin/waitForMySQL.sh"
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'rida'
    restart: always
  app:
    container_name: herniemp
    restart: always
    build: ./EmployeeService
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./EmployeeService:/app
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    command: bash -c "sleep 120 && mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

I know the `sleep 120` is shameful but with scripts put inside the volume property it gives me a permission denied message. Also the `link` option is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep these two containers in the same network. Consider following docker file for configuring in the same network:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: hernidb
    image: mysql
    volumes:
     - "./waitForMySQL.sh:/usr/local/bin/waitForMySQL.sh"
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:rida
    networks:
      movie-quote-network:
        aliases:
          - herni-database
    restart: always
  app:
    container_name: herniemp
    restart: always
    build: ./EmployeeService
    working_dir: /app
    networks:
      movie-quote-network:
        aliases:
          - herni-service
    volumes:
      - ./EmployeeService:/app
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    command: bash -c "sleep 120 && mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev"
    depends_on:
      - mysql

networks:
  herni-network:
```

As you can see, we’ve defined a network called herni-network at the bottom, with an empty body. I also added a networks section to each container configuration and providing an alias for that specific container.

Both containers will be able to communicate through each other by using the given alias as the hostname.